# How to say "challenge" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

I often use sentences such as "the challenges of doing...", "the challenges xx have to face" for my research.
I'm trying to translate that into Japanese, but I have trouble finding a word for "challenge". 課題 and 問題　have been suggested to me, but neither seems to fit perfectly. 課題 is probably more appropriate, but the meaning of "challenge" doesn't seem to be the main one.

Eg.

新規有機農家の課題は何ですか？ What are the challenges for new organic farmers?
有機農業を始める課題は。。。 The challenges of starting organic farming are...

Would these be okay in my case? Is there any better option?

Comment: The literal translation for challenge is 挑戦

Comment: ^ Weijun どういう意味で「literal translation」なのでしょうか？ 『ジーニアス英和辞典』(大修館)でchallenge(名詞)を引くと、一項目に「❶課題, 難問, やりがい, 覚悟」とあり、「挑戦」が出てくるのは２項目以降ですし、『レクシス英和』(旺文社)でも、上から「❶課題, 難問, やりがい, 意欲/興味をそそるもの, 力試し」「❷異議, 抗議, 疑義, 説明の要求」で、「挑戦」が出てくるのはやっと３項目なのですが。。。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

課題 and 問題 are both fine. However you should avoid the following expressions because these are ambiguous and tend to mean something else:

- 有機農業を始める課題 task of starting organic farming
- 新規有機農家の問題 problems with new organic farmers (farmers themselves are troublesome)

My recommendations:

- 新規有機農家が抱える課題
- 有機農業を始めるにあたっての課題
- 有機農業を始めるに際しての問題/課題

挑戦 basically only refers to the action of trying hard to achieve something difficult. I doubt we need this word in this context.

Comment: 「困難」はいかがでしょうか。英語で"challenge"のこういう使い方はだいたい難易度を表している気がします。もちろんこれは直訳すると"difficulty"なんですが、この場合"challenges"と"difficulties"を入れ替えてもあまり変わらないと思います。

Comment: @Mindful 英語の語感についてのコメント、大変勉強になります。「困難」は「今直面している問題」の意味には使えても、「これから挑む問題」の意味には使えないので、narutoさんの例文を全部は言い換えられないと思います。"difficulties"と同じだとすれば、「難しさ」と言い換えるのはいいかもしれません。

Comment: @broccoliforest こちらこそ「困難」の使い方について勉強になります。なるほどですね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 困難も良い候補だと思いますが、基本的には「困っている・苦しんでいる」という意味の単語なので、ちょっとネガティブ過ぎるかもしれません。